# How to investigate cucumber failures which fail with no description on CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I upgraded capybara from `v2.18.0` to `v3.12.0`. Now some of my cucumber features are failing with no reason like this:

```
..F..............................................................................................................................................

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/users/login:7 # Scenario: Login    
9 scenarios (1 failed, 8 passed)
44 steps (44 passed)
2m41.470s
```

It says that 1 scenario has failed but all the steps have passed

What is wrong with it?

How can I debug this issue?

I am using the following gem versions:

```
rails (5.1.2)
cucumber (3.1.2)
capybara (3.12.0)
selenium-webdriver (3.141.0)
```

I am running the tests with chromedriver `v2.45.615355` and google chrome `v72.0.3626.28-beta` in headless mode

Comment: Look at command line options for cucumber perhaps using a more verbose formatter will give you more info. (cucumber --help cucumber --format pretty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my CI test script from

```
bundle exec cucumber
```

to

```
bundle exec cucumber -b
```

and I was able to easily see the reason of the failure:

```
  execution expired (Timeout::Error)
  ...
  /builds/project/features/support/capybara_helper.rb:8:in `wait_until'
  /builds/project/features/support/capybara_helper.rb:21:in `block_and_wait_for_requests_complete'
  ...
```

It turned out that a timeout error was happening in the

```
After do
  block_and_wait_for_requests_complete
end
```

hook where I wait for all the JS and rack request to complete. `cucumber -h` describes `-b` option the following way:

> ```
> -b, --backtrace                  Show full backtrace for all errors.
> ```